# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Where does this series converges?

Using Ratio Test, I have checked that this series converges. Now I want to find the limit of this series.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}$$

I would like to have some hint.

Comment: This is not a power series, so I guess you're not asking the convergence interval, but the limit, right?

Comment: What do you mean the point of convergence?

Comment: Yes I am asking about the limit,@Ernie060

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I mean the limit of this series.

Comment: Is there any reason you suspect it has a nicely-representable limit?

Comment: @NickPeterson I checked using Ratio test that this series converges and I want to find the point at which it converges

Comment: Wolframalpha says it converges to some very nasty limit, approximately $.79$

Comment: How does this sum compare to $\sum \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$? Give upper and lower bounds with geometric series.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I understand that.  But having a limit and having a limit that can be written down in a nice closed form are two very, very different things.

Comment: @NickPeterson Sorry I misunderstood you then. I get your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no simple closed form for the summation but there is one
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}=\frac{2 \psi _2^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log (3)+i \pi}{\log (2)}\right)+2 i \pi +\log
   (18)}{\log (64)}$$ where appears the digamma function.

Numerically $S=0.79528027349537094149502809561786001318781240072533$

You could have a quite good approximation making
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}+\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}\approx \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}+\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
$$S\approx 2^{1-k}+\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+3}$$ Using $k=10$ would give
$\frac{99630343269857}{125276421276160}\approx 0.795284 $ which is not too bad.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general,

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+a}=\frac{2 \psi _2^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log (-a)}{\log (2)}\right)+2 \log (-a)+\log
   (2)}{a \log (4)}$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit can also be written as
$$ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-3/2)^k}{2^{k+1}-1}$$

But AFAIK there is no closed form.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense to me now!!